# Parse getCurrentUser() is returning null after login successful

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In an android app, which uses Parse, the login flow is like this...

We have our own logic to see if the user has entered the correct credentials. Once we verify that, signUpOrLoginOnParse() is called. Parse is used just to store data and handle sessions locally. Users can not access the api without the token.

```
private void signUpOrLogin(final String username, final String token) {
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(username);
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // sign up success. ParseUser.getCurrentUser() populated
                saveTokenToCloud(token);
            } else if ("condition to check if the user already exists") {
                // existing user, login.
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, username, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                        // login was successful, ParseUser.getCurrentUser() populated
                        saveTokenToCloud(token);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                showProgress(false);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void saveTokenToCloud(String token) {
    // saving token to cloud
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    user.put("token", token); // THIS IS WHERE I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    user.saveEventually();

    // link installation to user.
    ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    parseInstallation.put("user", user);
    parseInstallation.saveEventually();

    // Starting next activity
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

All good when I first run the app. Once, logout button is pressed (contains - `Parse.logoutInBackground()`), it shows the LoginActivity (current one). When trying to log in, everything succeeds but I get a NullPointerException at line 3 of saveTokenToCloud().

It says - trying to invoke virtual method .put() over a null object reference.

But, isn't Parse.currentUser() already populated since this method is called from callback of methods that do that ?

It works after restarting the app. But then the same continues if logout is pressed.

Comment: Did it work when you tried to get current user after save?

Comment: I hit logout and tried by deleting the user & installation object from parse data browser, the same result. It crashes !

Answer (score 0):

After calling logoutInBackground , future calls to getCurrentUser() will return null.

You will need to initialize the user again.

signUpInBackground will create a new ParseUser on the server, and also persist the session on disk so that you can access the user using ParseUser.getCurrentUser().
However i am not sure you should be calling it every single time you log in.

Instead of calling the getCurrentuser inside the saveToken method you can  pass the user to the saveTokenMethod from the done callback parameter.

Separate you logic in distinct methods for sign up and logIn. I suggest you check before calling signUp, and not abusing it every time you want to login

Comment: so, the logInInBackground() will not fetch the ParseUser and persist it locally ?

Comment: logInInBackground also saves the session to disk, so you can retrieve the currently logged in user using ParseUser.getCurrentUser().

Comment: Change the signUpInBackground callback for done like the logIn's callback: public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e). And check the user value then. But again, i don't recommend abusing the signUp every time, it may end up behaving like you don't expect.